# Can AlertDialog display a message with checkbox dialog?

Tags: android

I hope to get a dialog just like a.png, but the following code can't create the UI just like a.png.
How can I do? Thanks!

**[image: a.png]**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("The operation will spend long time!");
builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.Warning));
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(new String[] { "Don't display the message again" }, null, null);
builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    }
});

builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can AlertDialog display a message with checkbox dialog?

for showing any View in AlertDialog you should need to create custom layout for Dialog screen instead of using default see below example for creating custom AlertDialog :

[Android prompt user input dialog example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)

[Customize AlertDialog](http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/dialog-vs-alertdialog/)